# Over 100 internal links according to SEO testers, but we only have 36 pages

Tags: seo, links, navigation

According to a few SEO testers we use, we have over 100 internal links on our homepage, but we only have 41 pages linked on the homepage.

How can I work out where the duplicate internal links are coming from so I can start to fix things, or is this a common issue and nothing to worry about?

We have a responsive theme, and WordPress responsive menu & max mega menu plugins, which when disabled reduce the amount of duplicates a little, but not enough to make sense.

Comment: Online SEO testing sites, if that's what you mean by "SEO testers", are not infallible.  You can simply look at the source code for your Homepage and count up the links, if you only have 36 or 41 links... In any case, it's not really something to worry about. Duplicate pages, not links, are possibly more of an issue. In the future, please do not add your site's URL, we don't do individual SEO site reviews here. The question should contain all the information necessary to answer it, so that it's helpful to others as a reference in the future.

Comment: Google used to recommend limiting to 100 links but no longer gives out that advice.   Many sites that have great SEO have lots more than 100 links per page.  See https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/1257/14543

Comment: Agree with @StephenOstermiller. For simplicity, here's a Google video on the matter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHG6BkmzDEM In short your testers are providing a meaningless metric, at least without further context.

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about less than 100 internal links, you could easily check them by yourself.

Nonetheless, I'll recommend you to use Google Seach Console, where you can find a specific tool for [internal links](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/138752?hl=en) and also for [duplicate content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80407?hl=en) (based on title/description).

Data offered by this tool is very accurate.

Comment: We do use search console & we've not had any warning mesages about it. @stephen Ostermiller The seo testing websites like on Neil Patels website say we have over 100 links on the homepage however this is not intentional. We are supposed to have only 41 links on the homepage.

Comment: internal links tool shows pages linking to a page, not vice versa, so wont be much help in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the reason you are asking this question is because you have used some free SEO tool and its saying you have more than 100 links per page and thats bad.

100 links per page did used to be in Googles guidelines, it was based on Googles crawler only then [downloading 100 kilobytes](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/how-many-links-per-page/) of a page and the Google team arbitrarily deciding that 100 links per page was the maximum number of link a web page should have.

That was over 10 years ago, Google have since removed this from their guidelines and many website may have more than 100 links per page, but some free SEO tools have not removed this.   You do not need to worry if you have over 100 links per page, or have more than 1 link to the same page on a single page.

However, if you still would like to have an idea of the links on a page, use a fully featured SEO crawler such as [screaming frog](https://www.elephate.com/blog/ultimate-guide-seo-crawlers/)  (there are other [SEO crawlers](https://www.elephate.com/blog/ultimate-guide-seo-crawlers/)).

To do this in Screaming Frog go to: configuration > Spider > Limit

Set 'limit crawl depth' to 1.  (This will only crawl pages linked from the start page).

Add your home page as the starting page then start crawling.  Once complete, all the URLs listed on Internal and External tabs are linked from the home page. You can click each URL and then look in the the bottom window 'inlinks' tab for more info such as the anchor text used for the link.

You can also use the bulk export menu and export all outlinks as an excel doc.